# Hide top of content from external source in iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have som html that looks something like this...

**html**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left-col">
</div>
<div class="right-col">
<iframe src="external-site" border="0" scroll="no">
</div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.container {overflow:hidden;}
.right-col iframe {margin-top:-100px;}
```

I wanted to hide the 100 first top pixels of external site that is shown in the iframe. It seems to works in those browsers I have tested, but testing it on a "smart tv" without knowing what browser is used, there's an issue that not all the iframe is shown... BUT my question is therefore...

Is there any other way of achieving what I want to do?

Comment: try this way http://jsfiddle.net/6ddde5bg/ .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do following way.

```
.right-col iframe {
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
}
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6ddde5bg/)

Comment: Nice. Works quite well across multiple browsers.